# How to send data Thread to UiThread using handler and listening to a thread for response

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, android-handler

Using java (android studio)

I have this thread

```
void obtenerDatosBackground() {


    Thread EnviarCoordenadasHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            obtenerDatos();
        }
    });



    statusSync.CheckConnection(EnviarCoordenadasHilo);



}
```

and I have this in my code:

```
void configHandler()
{
    //con esto le digo al handler que esta adjuntado a la UI
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper() ){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

}
```

but I dont know how to set this handler to the thread.

Finally I use a listener for get result and update the UI but I got this message:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

I have read (a little) about [handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) but how can I to set a handler to (non UI) thread for update UI when I got the result

I have change the code to this but it yet dont work

```
void obtenerDatosBackground()
{
    Thread EnviarCoordenadasHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            obtenerDatos();
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() { //do what you want to do here
                     int uno=1;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    statusSync.CheckConnection(EnviarCoordenadasHilo);
}
```

**REMEMBER** 
I am using a listener for thread response

```
void setmListado()
{

    adapter = new VehiculoAdapter(getActivity(), mListado);
    lvListado.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvListado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            vehicleObject = (Vehiculo) adapter.getItem(i);
            edtEconomicNumber=vehicleObject.getNumeroEconomico();
            if(mListener!=null)
                mListener.onDismissResult(vehicleObject,edtEconomicNumber);
            else
                Log.w(getTag(),"Falta implementar OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    txtBuscar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //f_car_listado.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            //boolean uno=false;

            if (count < before) {
                // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                adapter.resetData();
            }
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

here I got the responde from thread

```
@Override
public void onFragmentFinished(boolean terminoBien, List<VehiculoResponseDTO> listado) {

    dialogFragment.dismiss();

    if(terminoBien)
    {

        if(listado.size()>0) {
            mListado = ListadoDTOaVehiculos(listado);
            //adapter = new VehiculoAdapter(getActivity(), mListado);
            //lvListado.setAdapter(adapter);
            setmListado();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            this.dismiss();
            f_seguimiento.DialogMensaje(getString(R.string.nohayvehiculos), getString(R.string.nohayvehiculosMensaje), true, null, getActivity());

        }
    }else
    {
            this.dismiss();
        f_seguimiento.DialogMensaje(getString(R.string.ocurrioProblema),getString(R.string.errorVehiculos),true,null,getActivity());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());                                                             
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//do what you want to do here
}
});
```

Comment: simply call the above code from the place from where u want to update your view.

Comment: void obtenerDatosBackground() {


    Thread EnviarCoordenadasHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            obtenerDatos();                                                                                                                                     Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());                                                             
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//do what you want to do here
}
});
        }
    });



    statusSync.CheckConnection(EnviarCoordenadasHilo);



}

Comment: do i need call thread.interrump()?? because with the code in your comment i am getting the same message and the code inside                     @Override
                    public void run() { //do what you want to do here
                         int uno=1;
                    } is never executed.

Comment: I have solved with handler.sendMessage() this video helped me:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaO1uHeIcj0

Comment: I have post the response here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39128406/586687

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved with this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaO1uHeIcj0):

and this is the code in simply steps:

this is my handler

```
void configHandler()
{
    //con esto le digo al handler que esta adjuntado a la UI
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper() ){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            setmListado();
        }
    };

}
```

I call configHandler on Oncreate

and on my listener (Remember it's running on (Non ui) Thread)

```
@Override
public void onFragmentFinished(boolean terminoBien, List<VehiculoResponseDTO> listado) {

    dialogFragment.dismiss();

    if(terminoBien)
    {

        if(listado.size()>0) {
            mListado = ListadoDTOaVehiculos(listado);
            //adapter = new VehiculoAdapter(getActivity(), mListado);
            //lvListado.setAdapter(adapter);
            Message message =Message.obtain();
            handler.sendMessage(message);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            this.dismiss();
            f_seguimiento.DialogMensaje(getString(R.string.nohayvehiculos), getString(R.string.nohayvehiculosMensaje), true, null, getActivity());

        }
    }else
    {
            this.dismiss();
        f_seguimiento.DialogMensaje(getString(R.string.ocurrioProblema),getString(R.string.errorVehiculos),true,null,getActivity());
    }
}
```

these lines:

```
 Message message =Message.obtain();
        handler.sendMessage(message);
```

call the code inside `configHandler()`
explicitly these lines:

```
  @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                setmListado();
            }
```

but what it work? because when handleMessage is call it is on UI thread and no in (Non UI) thread

in `configHandler()`
in this line using `Looper.getMainLooper()` I set this handler belongs to UI Thread

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper() )
```